# SPARQL/Spin update query for individuals

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, topbraid-composer

I uploaded the Ontology in the link, **edit sry something went wrong in the merging, this is now the acutaly file**. Ontology + mapping:  http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=06128684263999513543

I know it is kinda much to ask, but i hope somebody can help me out. Im really not experienced in this kind of field.

I need the following query explained in words which is part of a mapping:

write in every individual from type sequenceFlow(class) the object property split with assertion or (individual) and join with and(individual)(will be later edited in the process Ontology YAWL requeries this value for every sequenceFlow). Since the individuals are changing depending on the model and its part of a mapping it cant be done manually. Has to be applied like this.

Next check the class sequenceFlow and get all individuals from type sequenceFlow

If (sourceRef(object property) in sequenceFlow starts with the string inclusiveGateway (individual assertion), e.g the name of the individual is flow10 from type sequenceflow, write the object property split with the assertion or into the specific individual which was here e.g flow10.

Same procedure as above only with the object targetRef now, if targetRef include the first letters inclusiveGateway, write into the specific individual from tpye sequenceFlow join with the assertion or

This procedure has to be bone for all individuals from type sequence flow.
// inclusiveGateway usually increment by one, every time the modeler creates an instance, e.g inslusiveGateway1, 2

Guys i am really desperate and kinda under time pressure,i would appreciate help soooo much. I don't want to beg but you would help me really out and do me a big favour if you could create this query in respect to the Ontology. I am really kinda desperate at the moment, which I have to admit are also my fault at some point.

best regards
a man in trouble

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here.  You might get more responses if you describe your immediate problem, include what you have tried so far, and how you know (or why you suspect) that what you've tried so far isn't working.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I mean, you should obviously started with some SPARQL query resp. SPIN rule.

Comment: i tried t explain the querry in words, i hoped you could write it for me , due my little knowledge :(

Comment: sry i uploaded not the full ONtology, something went wrong while merging. I uploaded now the right files. Sorry for this!